# Yii2 Javascript fail to print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yii2, jquery-select2

This is my form field.

As can see, there is a div tag with details id right below the form field. I wanted to print the content inside the div tag out whenever I select the contact.

```
$url2 = yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('op-client/contact');
$this->registerJs($this->render('script2.js'), \yii\web\VIEW::POS_READY);

 $form->field($model, 'contact_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                              'data' => $getcontact,
                              'language' => 'en',
                              'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select'],
                              'pluginOptions' => [
                                  'allowClear' => true
                              ],
                              'pluginEvents' =>
                                    [
                                        'change' => 'function() 
                                          { 
                                             var contactid = $(this).val();
                                             getDetails(contactid);
                                             "'.$url2.'"
                                          }',
                                    ],
                          ]).'

                       <div id="details">

                        </div>
```

Script2.js

```
function getDetails(contactid,url2)
{
 var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");

console.log(contactid);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        cache:false,
        url:url2,
        data:{contactid:contactid, _crsf:csrfToken},
        success:function(data){
            $("#details").html(data);
            //document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = data;
        },
    })
}
```

Controller

```
public function actionContact()
    {
        $request = Yii::$app->request;

        $contact = $request->post('contactid');

        $contacts =OpContact::find()
                ->where(['id'=>$contact])
                ->one();

        echo $contacts->name;

    }
```

The problem seems like I cant print out the contact name. I can get the correct contact id but I cant print out the name inside the div tag, it just show blank onchange. Is there anything wrong with my calling method? Thanks

Comment: If you debug the `change` handler, what is the value of `contactid` at that moment?

Comment: @mariocatch it show the correct contactid

Comment: And if you debug `data` in the `success` handler of your ajax call, what is the value at that point?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by debug data? Blank I think? I try to print the data and it show [object Object] as output

Comment: Ok so what you want is probably in that object. Print it out to the console and inspect it. In the handler of `success`, `console.log(data);`, and check the debugger in your browser to see what properties it has.

Comment: I think something wrong with the 'data'. It shows something that is not related to it

Comment: give exit(); or die; after echo in controller and than log the value of data in console, and see what it prints.